# AWS Programmatically deploy instance for someone else (AWS CLI OAuth?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, oauth, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking for something that can programmatically spin up instances for other AWS users after oauth. Is there something like this that Amazon provides? So they can just login with AWS account and then I can make AWS calls on their behalf.

Is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 2):

There's no logging in here. You need a [cross-account role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html), supplied by the owner of the other account.

Comment: lol @jarmod I *promise* I did not copy your link.  Been working on that answer for several minutes, and saw yours once mine was posted.  Pretty funny that we chose the same page to cite, independently. +1

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No worries here. Your answer is better and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like this.

It would have massive security implications.

Note that the primary entity in AWS is not the user, it is the "account."  Accounts have users, and those users can only do what the account has authorized them to do.

For one AWS account ("mine") to allow another AWS account ("yours") to perform actions on behalf of my account (technically, not on behalf of "me"), I have to explicitly give you permission to do so, via IAM.  One solution is to create a role with the necessary permissions and [delegate access to you](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html).

But this is unlikely to be something a well-informed user would permit, since you could easily run up substantial expenses for the user.  Allowing such external access would not be a good practice.

There is, however, a way for users to launch your software on EC2 and optionally pay you a license fee billed on your behalf by AWS, through the [AWS Marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace), which is oriented towards a one-click experience for the user.

Comment: Hmm so there's no way for someone's account to give OAuth access? I don't want to spin up instances from my account for the other person's, I want the other account to directly give me access via OAuth and then I can make calls on their behalf programatically.

Something like this paradigm doesn't exist for AWS?

Comment: It doesn't exist in the user/login context, no.  You can make calls using your credentials against their account and its resources, if their account delegates the necessary permissions to you using IAM, as mentioned above.  When you use your credentials to `AssumeRole`, you're issued temporary credentials that allow you the delegated permissions they granted.